# Wordpress page template formatting not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates

I'm building a word pres theme and have found that formatting is not working. For example if I build a simple list in a post.

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

It works, but when I try it through a page it dose not apply the list element or any other element.

I have no idea why my page is not getting any formatting

**single.php**

```
**<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content-single', get_post_format() );

                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; endif;
            ?>

        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>**
```

**content_single.php**

```
<div class="blog-post">

<h2 class="blog-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<p class="blog-post-meta"><?php the_date(); ?> by <a href="#"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
```

//////////// And page /////////////////////

**page.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile; endif;
            ?>

        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**content.php**

```
<div class="blog-post">

    <h2 class="blog-post-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>

    <p class="blog-post-meta">
        <?php the_date(); ?>by <a href="#"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">
            <?php printf(_nx('One Comment', '%1$s Comments', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'textdomain'), number_format_i18n(get_comments_number())); ?>
        </a>
    </p>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php   the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php } ?>

</div><!-- /.blog-post -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in **page.php**  I change this

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile; endif;
        ?>

    </div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

to this

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

             <?php the_content(); ?>

        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```